How many cubic in the form $x^3-ax^2+(a+d)x-(a+2d)$ for integer $a$, $d$ have roots that are all non negative integers.?
How many cubic in the form $x^3-ax^2+(a+d)x-(a+2d)$ for integer $a$, $d$ have roots that are all non negative integers?

Welcome to Mathsstackexchange. Please use mathjax to edit a question. Before asking any question please search it in Approach zero website

https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/5058#5058

https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24x%5E2%2By%5E2%3D12z%5E2%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aintegers&p=1

Also show your attempts please, you should edit your question.

For the cubic case: Let the roots of your equation be $r_1, r_2,r_3$. By Vieta's formula we have:
$$r_1 + r_2 + r_3 = a$$
$$r_1r_2 + r_1r_3 + r_2r_3 = a+d$$
$$ \prod_{i=1}^3 r_i = a+2d$$
Can you solve that?
Hint: you can use the rational root theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem. It basically states that for a cubic polynomial $$p(x)=\sum_{n=0}^3 a_n x^n$$
with $a_n \neq 0$, if $r=\frac{m}{n}$ is a rational root of $p$, with co-prime $m$ and $n$ (so no dividing out common factors), then $m$ divides $a_0$ (a+2d in your case, this is the third equality above), and $n$ divides $a_n$ (1 in your case). What does that tell you?
